# Node.js - Express session data not persisting

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

login works as expected and session data returned but beyond that I am unable to get session data to persist. For example, when I call getUser (below) the session data is not returned.

**app.js (setup)**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const request = require('request')
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true
}))

const mongodb_conn_module = require('./mongodbConnModule');
var db = mongodb_conn_module.connect();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'work hard',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db,
        ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 // Keeps session open for 1 day
    })
}));
```

**app.js (login)**

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.logEmail && req.body.logPassword) {
        Users.authenticate(req.body.logEmail, req.body.logPassword, function (error, user) {
            if (error || !user) {
                var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
                err.status = 401;
                res.send("Wrong email or password.");
            } else {
                req.session.userId = user._id;
                res.send({
                    success: true,
                    sessionInfo: req.session
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        var err = new Error('All fields required.');
        err.status = 400;
        res.send("All fields required.");
    }
})
```

which returns session data (userId)
[image]

**app.js (getUser)**

```
app.get('/get_user', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.session)
})
```

which appears to drop session data
[image]

**UsersService.js (model)**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    passwordConf: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

//authenticate input against database
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function (email, password, callback) {
    Users.findOne({ email: email })
        .exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err)
            } else if (!user) {
                var err = new Error('User not found.');
                err.status = 401;
                return callback(err);
            }
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
            if (result === true) {
                return callback(null, user);
            } else {
                return callback();
            }
        })
    });
}

// hashing a password before saving it to the database
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    })
});

var Users = mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);
module.exports = Users;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please paste the code for Users.authenticate() and the Users model

Comment: Make sure that the session middleware is loaded before your routes.

Comment: @RohanDhar updated the post to include users.js model

Comment: @robertklep I'm fairly certain I'm loading my session middleware before the routes. app.get('/get_user',... and app.get('/login',... are defined after the session middleware is loaded.

Comment: Also check using your browser's developer tools if the session cookie is set after logging in, and if the same cookie is sent when requesting `/get_user`.

Comment: @robertklep just checked and the session cookie is **not** being set. any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry no. At first glance, your code looks okay so not sure why the cookie isn't being set.

Comment: @robertklep odd... I see the cookie set in Safari but not in Chrome. although, the session data is still not persisting

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the same issue after a lot of work, because order  not good in app.js (setup), so edit app.js  (setup) by this code hope helped you :)

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const request = require('request')
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const app = express()
    app.use(session({
            secret: 'work hard',
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            cookie: {
                secure: false,
                maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            },
            store: new MongoStore({
                mongooseConnection: db,
                ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 // Keeps session open for 1 day
            })
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.use(morgan('combined'))
    app.use(cors({
        credentials: true
    }))
});
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true
}))

const mongodb_conn_module = require('./mongodbConnModule');
var db = mongodb_conn_module.connect();


}));
```

Comment: I re-ordered per your suggestion without success